# Unsupported media type 415 при отправке fetch запроса в ApiController

Tags: c#, fetch, asp

Фетч возвращает 415, при этом подозрительно быстро и без срабатывания брекпоинтов даже в начале метода.
У меня есть ApiController

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class SiteApiController : ControllerBase
{
    // 
}
```

Есть апи метод (два нижних атрибута уже потом добавил после гуглений)

```
[HttpPost("find")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public HttpResponseMessage Find([FromBody] JsonElement search)
{
    // тут код, но с фетчем не срабатывает даже брекпоминт на первой строчке
}
```

Есть JS с фетчем в разметке

```
const req = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(`{'search':'${text}'}`)
            };
            fetch("/api/find", req)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("then -> " + res.text());
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(json => {
                    console.log("then -> " + json);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
```

Сам Program

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "api",
    pattern: "api/{action}");
```

Самое смешное. что через PostMan все отправляется. Уже весь интернет облазил, не понимаю ничего (

Comment: уберите mode: 'no-cors' в request-ах и убедитесь, что ваше api возвращает в заголовке Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: А почему no-cors идет в запросе неявно?

Comment: почитайте тут https://blog.gelin.ru/2018/12/cors.html

Comment: если бы у вас был только такой Content-Type со значением application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data или text/plain, то всё бы проходило, но у вас application/json. Поэтому вам нужен cors и соответствующие заголовки в ответе сервера.